# Firebase assigning moderator status with UID

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to allow specific persons to edit the data on the Firebase Database that users are not allowed to edit.

I am allowing by simply allowing them to write with their user ids:

```
".write": "auth != null && auth.uid === 'h7yic7LeS123asdfsdgwPrfKZ2'"
```

Is this a safe method? Do I have to use token based authentication to assign roles to the moderators?

Comment: As a tip, if you have `auth.uid === <...>` you don't need `auth != null`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a standard way to authenticate your user (i.e. login) like, e.g. Firebase UI (https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web), this is indeed a safe method.

As a matter of fact, using such an authentication mechanism will populate auth.uid with the uid of the user and therefore only user with uid h7yic7LeS123asdfsdgwPrfKZ2 will be able to write to the corresponding database node.

Since you are mentioning "specific personS" (i.e. more than one user) you may use a different approach than hardcoding the users' uid in the security rule. You could, for example, use a rule like this one:

```
".write": "auth != null && root.child('admins/' + auth.uid).exists()"
```

In this case you would declare the uids of the authorised persons as children of the "admins" database node:

```
-admins
  -h7yic7LeS123asdfsdgwPrfKZ2: true
```

Comment: Ya beat me to it.